# _beginthreadex and _endthreadex is undefined even when process.h is included

Tags: c++, dll, dllexport

I m using embarcadero IDE and i have an issue when creating a DLL project. when I use the function _beginthread. All the time when I compile the DLL project I have this error _beginthread is undefined even when process.h is included.

I thank you for your help.

Comment: They are functions in the Microsoft CRT, necessary in the previous century.  Wrong century and wrong company.  Consider TThread or std::thread or google "c++ builder create thread".

Comment: You need to download WinSDK or use visual studio.Latest SDK - https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/windows-10-sdk

Comment: Also you can use TDM GCC with Codelite IDE,TDM GCC provide necessary WinAPI libs.
http://tdm-gcc.tdragon.net/download
https://codelite.org/

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all your answers.

I have resolve my Issue.
The solution is to set the option Multi-thread when you create the DLL project and also include process.h

Comment: Do you know what this changes in the project configuration? I changed C++ Builder versions and now I have this problem. How can I enable this for an existing project?